# How to differentiate scripts from humans when they do password-based ssh to my server?

Tags: linux, ssh, syslog

How do I detect if a particular ssh login was made by running a script or was it a user who typed password?

I want to detect script based logins. 'auth.log' doesn't give me this info. Is there any other logging mechanism available?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly.

You can guess that some session was made by a robot, if there is a short time gap between login and a first command (and next commands), but smart bots can fake human hesitation and execute commands with typos too.

It is usually enough to provide users a 'legal' way to automate some tasks. If you, as sysadmin, will give your users some official logins for robots, provide easy way to do the scripting, and monetary punish users for scripting under their own accounts...

On a corporate level it usually works. It won't save you from dedicated hackers, but can reduce the number of amateur ones.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps.